# update data and GET data with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to show data by modal Bootstrap and also updates the data with ajax but it can not be done together, how to be able to display the data and update the data on codeigniter?

My views ajax

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_note('<?php echo $row->id_note; ?>');">unread</a>

function show_note(id_note) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('my_controll/note_update')?>/" + id_note,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#note').val(data.note);
            $('#note_show').modal('show'); 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error ajax');
        }       
    });     
}
```

Controllers

```
function note_update($id_note) {    
    $data = $this->M_model->detail_note($id_note);
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

Models

```
function detail_note($id_note) {    
    $this->db->set('status_note', '0');
    $this->db->where('id_note', $id_note);              
    $this->db->update('table_note', $data);  

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('table_note')
                      ->where('id_note', $id_note)
                      ->get();
    return $query->row();                   
}
```

Comment: did you check the initial value of `id_note`?

Comment: yes i want to display data from id_note and update data when clicked

Comment: I meant: where does `$row->id_note` come from? you don't show it, but it should be from another controller, right? Did you check, if it has a value?

Comment: `$row->id_note` data from another controller foreach, I shorten it on my question. and it was not problematic. so that a problem can not execute to two commands that update data and display data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this..

Controller:

```
function note_update($id_note) {    
    $data = $this->M_model->detail_note($id_note);
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

Model :

```
function detail_note($id_note) {    
    $this->db->set('status_note',0);
    $this->db->where('id_note', $id_note);              
    $this->db->update('table_note');  

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('table_note')
                      ->where('id_note', $id_note)
                      ->get();
    return $query->row_array();                   
}
```

Don't forget load `url` helper and yor ajax must be like this..

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_note('<?php echo $row->id_note; ?>');">unread</a>

function show_note(id_note) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('my_controll/note_update');?>/"+id_note,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#note').val(data.note); 
        },
       complete: function(data){
         $('#note_show').modal('show');
         },
        error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error ajax');
        }       
    });     
}
```

Comment: thanks @Hikmat Sijapati, still the same error message, `Error ajax` data is updated but does not appear modal bootstrap

Comment: what is output on `console.log(data);`

Comment: concolse.log of the results of all the data appears and is actualized, but form modal not appear. Now the problem is not showing the form modal, so I want when clicked perform modal form appears the data is updated.